# Front mech chain tension: rub or no downshift

Tags: derailleur-front, tiagra

I replaced the cable/housing on my Tiagra 4700 front mech and I'm having trouble adjusting the cable tension just right.

It seems I'm stuck between two undesirable states: if I get the cable tension high enough so that the front mech's outer plate doesn't rub on the chain when on the big ring, then I'm not able to downshift.

On the other hand, if I slacken the cable tension to the point where I can downshift, then the chain rubs terribly on the outer plate when I'm on the big ring (throughout pretty much the whole rear range, but the smaller cog on the rear, the worse the rubbing is on the front).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the "tense" position, do you have enough clearance for "biggie/smalls", i.e. your hardest gear? I'm not sure what Shimano recommends, but 1 mm between mech and chain shouldn't be too much to avoid overshifting/dropping the chain.

Comment: Yes, in "tense" there's nothing rubbing, even with big ring and smallest sprocket. But then I can't go down to the small ring in the front...

Comment: Perhaps it is just best to go from scratch by the definitive resource for such cases: https://youtu.be/ZNG7g83lI-s?si=z8MZBaEGeS30dA0u

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was a case of the end of the shifter cable not being seated properly in the brifter.